# system crash randomly while using adobe flash

Tags: flash

My system crashes usually while using adobe flash

- Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
- Intel® Ivybridge Desktop
- 64-bit
- 7.7 GB RAM

I found the following  entries in the log before it did crash:

```
May 28 15:46:15 lenny kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
May 28 15:46:15 lenny rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="922" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May 28 15:46:15 lenny rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
May 28 15:46:15 lenny rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
May 28 15:46:15 lenny rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
May 28 15:46:15 lenny avahi-daemon[924]: avahi-daemon 0.6.30 starting up.
```

Answer (score 2):

When I'm working on Adobe Flash Hits me the program and writes a crash flash file and that of this record-keeping on the surface Almkntb

Answer (score 1):

There is no question here.
Adobe flash is not maintained anymore on linux and it got bugs.
Your logs does not represent anything that could give a hint. 
Try to use opensource version of Adobe Flash:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightspark

Remember about HTML5 which actually is supported by youtube and other websites.

Regards